# Log4J2: Substituting Parameters does not work properly

Tags: java, logging, parameters, log4j2, substitution

Im using Log4J 2.8.2.

The manual (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/api.html) says that substituting Parameters is better done with placeholders:

That means

```
logger.debug("Logging in user {} with birthday {}", user.getName(), user.getBirthdayCalendar());
```

is better  than

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    logger.debug("Logging in user " + user.getName() + " with birthday " + user.getBirthdayCalendar());
}
```

because:

> the logging level will only be checked once and the String
>   construction will only occur when debug logging is enabled.

So lets say I have following two methods:

```
public static String getSentence() {
        System.out.println("Sentence Invoked!");
        return "{} im the Best!";
    }

    public static String expensiveOperation() {
        System.out.println("Expensive Invoked!");
        return "John Doe";
    }
```

Now the Level of the rootLogger is set to `INFO`. If I log the following way:

```
LOGGER.debug(getSentence(), expensiveOperation());
```

I get following output:

```
Sentence Invoked!
Expensive Invoked!
```

That means both methods are invoked, although there is no logging happening because `LOGGER`'s Level is `DEBUG` and rootLoggers's Level is `INFO`.

I would have expected that neither of the methods `getSentence()` and `expensiveOperation()` would be invoked. Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logs are filtered based on the log levels set (Handler will only receive the filtered logs). but jvm does executes every logs.